# Rails - bookings not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm building an Event site using Rails. When creating an event the user is able to offer both paid and free events. It appears that a `booking_id` is being allocated only to paid events not for free events. I've checked my console and this is definitely the case. This is obviously causing issues and I'm not quite sure how to resolve.

Here's my code:

#### bookings_controller.rb

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    # booking form
    # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
    @booking = @event.bookings.new
    # which person is booking the event?
    @booking.user = current_user
    @booking.quantity = @booking.quantity
    @total_amount = @booking_quantity.to_f * @event_price.to_f

end

def create
    # actually process the booking
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user
    #@total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f

    Booking.transaction do
        @booking.save!
        @event.reload
        if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
        flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
        end 
    end

    if @booking.save

        # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
        # #{} == puts a variable into a string
        Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @event.price_pennies, currency: "gbp",
            card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")

        flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
        flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
        render "new"
    end

    if @event.is_free?

        @booking.save!
        flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    end
end

private

def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
end

end
```

events_controller.rb

```
 class EventsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy,]
# the before_actions will take care of finding the correct event for us
# this ties in with the private method below
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
# this ensures only users who are signed in can alter an event

def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @events = Event.not_yet_happened.order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @events = Event.not_yet_happened.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
    # The above code = If there's no category found then all the events are listed
    # If there is then it will show the EVENTS under each category only
end

def show
end

def new
    @event = current_user.events.build
    # this now builds out from a user once devise gem is added
    # after initially having an argument of Event.new
    # this assigns events to users
end

def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
    # as above this now assigns events to users
    # rather than Event.new

    if @event.save
        redirect_to @event, notice: "Congratulations, you have successfully created a new event."
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    # edit form
    # @edit = Edit.find(params[:id])
    @event = current_user.events.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    if @event.update(event_params)
        redirect_to @event, notice: "Event was successfully updated!"
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @event.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

private

def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :location, :date, :time, :description, :number_of_spaces, :is_free, :price, :organised_by, :url, :image, :category_id)
    # category_id added at the end to ensure this is assigned to each new event created
end

def find_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end







end
```

#### Booking table

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "event_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "stripe_token"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.integer  "quantity"
end
```

I've added `@booking.save!` into the create method for free events but no change. I've also added the transaction code block in order to avoid over-booking but this only works for paid events. Any assistance, appreciated.

Comment: did you try to comment out the "redirect_to event_path(@event)" line ?

Comment: I would recommend using 'pry' gem to debug. You can put binding.pry before and after save to double check your params are there or if it got saved and rolled back at the end of transaction.

Comment: It seems you are trying to create an event and the foreign_key booking id is not getting stored in Events table? Am I right? Then please share your Events controller and form code.

Comment: Please add your log to the question..

see `log/development.log` (or whatever enivornment you're in)

Comment: A suggestion, your `Booking.transaction` logic seems like can be and should be moved to the model validations.

Comment: I noticed in your controller `create` action you end up calling `@booking.save` 3 separate times. You should only need to call that once in the method. I don't know if that causes your particular issue, just something to note. Like the others said, would need to see your form/logs to really assist a lot more; can't find any major logic bugs in the code you posted :)

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but shouldn't `@event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces` actually be  `@event.bookings.sum(:quantity) > @event.number_of_spaces`

Comment: `@event.bookings.build` ?

Comment: Events Controller has now been added as per request above.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing your `create` action method, I have found the following checks:

- check if the event will be out of capacity after including new quantity
- save the booking

  - if the event is free, we are done
  - else we try to create the Stripe::Charge

So the `create` action might look like:

```
def create
  # actually process the booking
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
  @booking.user = current_user
  #@total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f

  if ( @event.bookings.sum(&:quantity) + @booking.quantity ) > @event.number_of_spaces
    flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  end

  if @booking.save
    if @event.is_free?
      flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
      redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
      begin
        Stripe::Charge.create(
          amount: @event.price_pennies,
          currency: "gbp",
          source: @booking.stripe_token,
          description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}"
        )

        flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
        redirect_to event_path(@event)
      rescue => e
        @booking.destroy  # delete the entry we have just created
        flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
        render "new"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, you need to refactor the code well enough to ensure that your controller does not become *fat*

Comment: Sorry it's been so long to respond but I've been away. How will the above code allocate a booking id to free events?

Comment: please look at the condition if @booking.save. If the condition is successful, then a booking id will be created irrespective of the event type (free/paid).